# How to send custom values in google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, tag-manager, analytics-events

I am working on tag certain events with google tag manager but I have a doubt about sending custom value, I'm defined an event like this

[image]

In the value field I'm sending a data layer value defined as monthly_income so in javascript I set the event like this

```
<button  name="calculate-by-monthly-income" class="btn btn-primary tab" ng- click="calculateByMonthlyIncome()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" onclick="dataLayer.push({'monthly_income': '10000'});ga('send', 'event', 'Calculadora1', 'Calcular', 'Event');">
   Calcular
</button>
```

I'm not sure if it is the right way to set the value field

regards

Comment: You would need to also push an "event" into the dataLayer so that you can use that to acquire the monthly_income value. Without it, it would very difficult for you to get the monthly_income because you wouldn't know which dataLayer object to fetch the value from.